# where does the official, "non-custom firmware" Android os look for version updates?

Tags: updates, operating-system

When the "new update is available" popup appears on the screen, does the os go to the manufacturer's server or the google's servers to download the update? in other words who is the main version update publisher that the os looks for updates from?

Comment: Always the manufacturer provides the updates.

Comment: You can actually figure this out by yourself by intercepting the network request from your OS updater software/app. We have related posts if you need help with that.

Comment: If the phone is not out of date and still receives updates, there is an old popular network monitor tool named "Fiddler" for windows , and there is a similar android app called fiddler too. For SSL it can produce a user defined certificate and takes the middle of connection through a vpn. And it is usually on one of the google servers.

Answer (score 2):

The OS looks for updates from the manufacturer's site for a newer version. When you click download on your phone it download the latest update usually as "update.zip".